# How to submit a pyspark application using Spark API rest files passing by a collection of python files, equivalent approach of --py-files

Tags: python, rest, apache-spark, pyspark, submit

I'm working in a pyspark application which I am able to successfully submit to spark using command line

```
spark-submit --master "spark://192.168.93.42:7077" --name "TopologyDiscovery" --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true  --py-files /opt/bitnami/spark/application/pyoneer-0.0.1-py3.11.egg /opt/bitnami/spark/application/app.main.py --start 2018-09-21 --end 2018-09-22 --trafoids SIM01
```

My application is composed by an python entrypoint *app.main.py* to be executed as a driver, that will be importing the python module which is embedded in the *egg* file. This is why I use --py-files to make spark understand I have that extra *egg* file with the app business logic.

I'm struggling to replicate the same behaviour but submitting the Job using the Spark Rest API.

```
{
    "appResource": "/opt/bitnami/spark/application/pyoneer-0.0.1-py3.11.egg",
    "sparkProperties": {
        "spark.master": "spark://192.168.93.42:7077",
        "spark.eventLog.enabled": "true",
        "spark.app.name": "TopologyDiscovery",
        "spark.driver.supervise": "false",
        "spark.submit.deployMode": "client",
        "spark.jars":"/opt/bitnami/spark/application/pyoneer-0.0.1-py3.11.egg"       
    },
    "clientSparkVersion": "3.2.1",
    "mainClass": "org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit",
    "environmentVariables": {
        "SPARK_ENV_LOADED": "1"
    },
    "action": "CreateSubmissionRequest",
    "appArgs": ["file:/opt/bitnami/spark/application/app.main.py","--start", "2018-09-21", "--end", "2018-09-22", "--trafoids", "SIM01"]
}
```

This is the logs with the specific error I got executing the driver Entrypoint app.main.py

```
Running topology discovery for start=2018-09-21, end=2018-09-22, trafoid=['SIM01']
File --> /opt/bitnami/spark/application/app.main.py
File Name -->  app.main.py
Module is going to be loaded -->app.main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/spark/application/app.main.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/bitnami/spark/application/app.main.py", line 51, in main
    module = importlib.import_module("app.main")
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

For me is clear, that I'm not indicating well in the post request where is my egg file that contain the module "app". I have tried putting the path, in appResource or in Spark.jars fields, but I was not able to find what is the equivalence with the --py-files argument that you can use when from spark command line

I have tried several combinations of Post requests, indicating the path to egg file in the appArgs, appResource, spark.jars...

---

As a possible workaround I have tried to simulate how I think command-line is doing with this --pyFiles arguments.

[adding a new appArg called "eggFile" into the Post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gakbt.png)

[Adding to python sys.path the path to the provided Egg file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckMRq.png)

With this workaround, driver job is able to import the python module app.main inside of the egg file, so app business layer is executed.

I would say must be a more proper way of following the same idea but using some existing parameter to be filled in the Spark Rest request